# ASP.NET HtmlTableで行データが正しく取得できない。

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

テーブルに実際には2行あるのに、HtmlTableコントロールから1行しか読めないです。

まずaspxファイルにはテーブルがあります。

```
    <table runat="server" id="datatable" border="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>名前</td><td>年齢</td><td>部署</td><td>備考</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

ページロード時にサーバー側で下記のようにデータを追加しておきます。

```
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
// rowにデータ格納する
datatable.Rows.Add(row);
```

これでデータが2行になって表示されます。

でも、POSTされたときに

```
int n = datatable.Rows.Count;
```

で行数を取得しても1が返ってきます、

Answer (score 1):

おそらくASP.NETの仕様通りの動作です。コードビハインドで`HtmlTableRow`を追加した場合、自動的に以前のデータは復元されません。

なぜこうなっているかというと、前提としてWebブラウザがサーバーに送信してくる情報が`input`などの特定の要素に限定されるです。なのでASP.NETでは`table`や`span`などを出力する`WebControl`のプロパティを保存するために、[ビューステート](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms178198%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)と呼ばれる情報を`hidden`に出力し、次のリクエストの初期段階でプロパティを復元しています。しかし`HtmlTable`はそのような動作を意図していない`HtmlControl`であるため、ビューステートから行を復元することはありません。

考えられる対応としては、

- `GridView`などのより高機能なWebコントロールを使用する
- 各リクエストで`HtmlTable`に出力する情報を取得する
- 必要な情報を自分で`ViewState`に入出力して`HtmlTable`の状態を復元する

などがあると思います。